# Dell 2408 wont read sd cards bigger than 2gb?

Tags: sd-card

I've been using my monitors sub card reader for ages, but now I can't seem to be able to read anything more than 2gb using the reader.

Is this a hardware restriction or can I update my drivers for the monitor, which I can't seem to find, to be able to read the larger cards. If not, how do I select a card reader which will read larger cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your monitor is at all modern, it should be able to read large SD cards. try to reinstall the drivers. If that doesn't work, you can pick up a cheap SD card reader from NewEgg for less than $10 that will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. it has an SD card reader. SDcard only go up to 2GB. If you plug in a SDHC or SDXC card then it weill fail to read it. If I try this with an SDHC card and windows 7 then the explorer seems to freeze.

Solutions:

- Buy a more modern reader (optionally plug that into on of the monitors USB ports)
- Or only use SD cards and no SDHC or SDXC cards.

For reference:
SD: UP to 2GB
SDHC: >2 GB to 32 GB
SDXC: >32 GB to 2 TB